# storing the sentences with space in vb6

Tags: mysql, vb6

hello everyone I want to ask that if I have text form and then I store those text in database it make a space in the left and right the sentence 
for example I put in the text form symbols like CS340D then is stored in a database like this ' CS340D ' space in the previous and after the symbol ,,this makes a problem for me

this my insert code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
cnDB.Execute "INSERT INTO attendance (SNO,s_section,Time) VALUES(' " &    Text1.Text & " ',' " & Text2.Text & " '
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely your `INSERT INTO` query will work as shown in your question, because your `VALUES` clause lacks the closing parenthesis.

```
VALUES(' " &    Text1.Text & " ',' " & Text2.Text & " '
```

And, you are putting the spaces into your database columns with this query.

This becomes, after text substitition

```
 VALUES(' CS340D ',' somethingElse '
```

You probably` want it to look like this after substitution.

```
 VALUES('CS340D','somethingElse')
```

To get that, try this.

```
VALUES('" & Text1.Text & "','" & Text2.Text & "')"
```

And, you must clean up those text values or subject yourself to the risk of a SQL injection attack on your system.  What if somebody gives you, for a Text2 value, this

```
 You are pwned!'); DROP TABLE attendance; --
```

After substitution you get

```
VALUES('CS340D','You are pwned!'); DROP TABLE attendance; --')
```

which would spoil your week.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, first we will correct your sql statement, prevent sql injection then add one space each on the start and end of the strings.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim text1 As String
Dim text2 As String

text1= Replace$(Text1.Text, "'", "''")
text2= Replace$(Text2.Text, "'", "''")

cnDB.Execute "INSERT INTO attendance (SNO,s_section,Time) VALUES('" & Space(1) & text1 & Space(1) & "',' " & Space(1) & text2 & Space(1) & "')"
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works...